# Getting history of android hardware usage if app is installed as system app

Tags: android, bluetooth, gps

May I monitor hardware like GPS or Bluetooth in android if my app is installed as system application?

I am doing a project in which I prepared history of internet usage and now want to monitor GPS but found that it is not possible in android unless you have custom ROM.

Is there any way to monitor these resources ff I root my device and install the app as a system app?

Comment: What exactly you want to monitor for  GPS and Bluetooth?

Comment: I want to know which application is using my GPS at what time same for Bluetooth and maintain record with time stamp